# Python requests problem with Wordpress API

Tags: python, wordpress, python-requests, wordpress-rest-api

I 'm trying to use Wordpress REST API for my Wordpress website, it's working when I use `curl` or requesting the URL from my `browser`, but when using python requests `get` method, I get 404 error

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://myWebsiteDomain.com/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/categories')
print(r.status_code)

>>> 404
```

Comment: Inspect `r.content` to see what you actually got together with the 404. A lot of times, APIs will return some info in the body of the response

Comment: Add header to add any useragent. And I mean literally "any" - I just put "test" and it worked. :P It seems default requests useragent is being cut out on the server's side, probably some anti-spam filtering by headers.

Comment: @h4z3 wow that is embarrassing, I was confused because I even put the Authentication headers and it's still didn't work , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [h4z3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11516012/h4z3) comment the request needs a header containing a User-Agent

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://myWebsiteDomain.com//blog/wp-json/wp/v2/categories', headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)

>>> 200
```